# MongoDB - Find document by _id and return without child elements by value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to return a document, but exclude some child fields based on status. For example if the status is disabled then I don't want that child returned. But all the other records returned if they don't contain disabled.

The request includes the `_id` of the document that I want to find and return, without the 'disabled' child records.

How do I select the document by `_id` then, exclude records from the child array based on a value.

Thanks

My document look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e7bb266071f9601b6ad8f4e"),
    "name" : "Test Document",
    "postcode" : "90210",
    "colors" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e7d276a05674f0cf49bdcec"),
            "color" : "blue",
            "status": "active"

        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e7d276a05674f0cf49bdceg"),
            "color" : "red",
            "status": "active"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e7d276a05674f0cf49bdceh"),
            "color" : "green",
            "status" : "disabled"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I return:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e7bb266071f9601b6ad8f4e"),
    "name" : "Test Document",
    "postcode" : "90210",
    "colors" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e7d276a05674f0cf49bdcec"),
            "color" : "blue",
            "status": "active"

        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e7d276a05674f0cf49bdceg"),
            "color" : "red",
            "status": "active"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have been trying variations of:

```
    findr.aggregate([

        {
            $match: {
                $and: [{
                    _id: mongodb.ObjectId(_id)
                }, {
                    'color.status': 'active'
                }]
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id
                name: 1,
                postcode: 1,
                colors: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: '$colors',
                        as: 'color',
                        cond: {
                            $eq: ['$$color.status', 'active']
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for filteration.

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": ObjectId("5e7bb266071f9601b6ad8f4e")
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      items: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$colors",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$item.status",
              "active"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zgJa-XujigH)